# Classification of Galois covering maps over a bouquet of 2 circles

Tags: covering-spaces, galois-connections

The b-sheeted Galois covering maps over $C^*$ are equivalent to $z\mapsto z^b$.

I wonder if there is an analogous statement for such Galois covers over C except two points $0,1$.
Is that true that the b-sheeted Galois cover over $C\backslash \{0,1\}$ is equivalent to
$$ (z,w)\in\{ w^b -z(z-1)=0\} \mapsto z \; ?
$$

Thank you.

Comment: I figured that this is better suited as a comment : Your class of covers is countable, whereas there are uncountable many finite-sheeted Galois covers of $\Bbb C-\{0, 1\} \cong S^1 \vee S^1$ as $F_2$ contains uncountably many normal subgroups of finite index. So the class you mention surely misses a lot of covers.

Comment: Thank you.
This is indeed actually false when the number of the sheets is 4.